# GMail API authorization code

Tags: gmail-api

I try to connect from my App (Spring Boot application) to Gmail API in order to download some of my mail. It actually works, but I have a problem with authorization. When I call authorize() method, it gives me a auth link in IDE console. Is there any way to redirect user to authorization page instead of print this link in console?

My code:

```
public Credential authorize() throws IOException
{
    InputStream inputStream = GTD.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build();

    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");

    System.out.println("Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
    return credential;
}

public Gmail getGmailService() throws IOException
{
    Credential credential = authorize();

    return new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                    .setApplicationName("GTD")
                    .build();
}
```

**EDIT: When I call functions from normal Java App, not web application, it works.**

Comment: Did you properly [authorize your app with Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth) and use the proper [scope](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes)?

Comment: @KENdi I have enabled Gmail API and I have OAuth 2.0 client IDs credential (Other Type). Scope - ReadOnly.